# Modificar query para ingresar un dato a una tabla. SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
 SELECT A.CardName FROM OCRD A 
 INNER JOIN OSLP B ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode = 1 AND LicTradNum = 'XAXX010101000'
```

Me genera un listado de clientes que le corresponden al vendedor con ID(SlpCode es la columna para identificar a los vendedores) número 1.

Necesidad: Asignarle a cada vendedor un elemento más que se llame "Ventas mostrador" en la columna `CardName`. A esto se tiene que modificar el código, pero no se de qué manera le puedo asignar a TODOS los vendedores ese elemento.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres. Que significa asignarle un elemento más en la columna CardName?

Comment: No guardarlo en la tabla, ya que sería mucho rollo guardar el elemento por cada vendedor, si no mostrar "Ventas mostrador" para cualquier vendedor.

Comment: Pero mostrarlo como?, Te refieres a que, suponiendo que el valor de un CardName sea Elizabeth, entonces la sentencia te devuelva "Ventas mostrador Elizabeth"??

Comment: Sería:
1. Ventas mostrador, 2.Elizabeth, 3.Arturo, 4.Alan

Comment: Pues hacerlo con SELECT ‘Ventas Mostrador’ UNION ALL SELECT A.CardName...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo debes añadirle el `string` con la información que le quieres asignar a cada registro

```
SELECT 'Ventas Mostrador', A.CardName FROM OCRD A 
INNER JOIN OSLP B ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode = 1 AND LicTradNum = 'XAXX010101000'
```

Si quieres añadirle un alias a esa columna, (ya que por defecto la creará con el nombre **Sin nombre de columna**), le agregas un `AS`

```
SELECT 'Ventas Mostrador' AS NombreColumna, A.CardName FROM OCRD A 
INNER JOIN OSLP B ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode = 1 AND LicTradNum = 'XAXX010101000'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Paulo y  @DevCodeG